# a data property changed can not effect button's disabled in elementui

Tags: vue.js, frontend

Here is the situation:
There are multiple people involved in this function, and this page needs to show the correct action according to their post

here are codes:

```
 <el-table :data="form.stage1_xmglXmRgcbmxList" border max-height="250" style="width: 100%">
              <el-table-column align="center" label="序号" type="index" width="50"/>
              <el-table-column align="center" label="一级部门">
                <template slot-scope="scope">
                  <el-select v-model="scope.row.deptId1" placeholder="请选择" size="mini" @change="handleDept1Changed(scope.row)"
                             :disabled="!scope.row.hasAuth">
                    <el-option v-for="item in rgcbflmxOptions" :key="item.DEPT_ID" :label="item.DEPT_NAME" :value="item.DEPT_ID"/>
                  </el-select>
                </template>
              </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column align="center" label="二级部门">
                <template slot-scope="scope">
                  <el-select v-model="scope.row.deptId2" placeholder="请选择" size="mini" @change="handleDept2Changed(scope.row)"
                             :disabled="!scope.row.hasAuth">
                    <el-option v-for="item in getDictChildren(rgcbflmxOptions, scope.row.deptId1)" :key="item.DEPT_ID"
                               :label="item.DEPT_NAME" :value="item.DEPT_ID"/>
                  </el-select>
                </template>
              </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column align="center" label="工作量(人/天)" width="120">
                <template slot-scope="scope">
                  <el-input v-model="scope.row.gzNum" :disabled="!scope.row.hasAuth" size="mini" type="text" @input="handleCalcCostOfRow(scope.row)" />
                </template>
              </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column align="center" label="操作" width="100">
                <template slot="header">
                  <el-button @click="handleAdd('stage1', 'labor')" size="mini" type="success" :disabled="!sqXmfyEditable">添加</el-button>
                </template>
                <template slot-scope="scope">
                  <el-button :disabled="!scope.row.hasAuth" size="mini" type="danger" @click="handleDelete(scope.row, scope.$index, 'labor')">删除</el-button>
                </template>
              </el-table-column>
            </el-table>

data() {
    return {
        sqRgcbEditable: false,
      sqXmfyEditable: false,
      otdRgcbEditable: false,
      otdXmfyEditable: false,
      onenRgcbEditable: false,
      onenXmfyEditable: false,
      csRgcbEditable: false,
      csXmfyEditable: false,
    }
}

methods:{
    analysisAuth(row){
      if(row.stage=='stage1' && this.user.posts.some(item=>item.postCode=='GSPGSQ(530)')){
        row.hasAuth=true
        this.sqRgcbEditable=true
        this.sqXmfyEditable=true
      }else if(row.stage=='stage2' && this.user.posts.some(item=>item.postCode=='GSPGOTD(530)')){
        row.hasAuth=true
        this.otdRgcbEditable=true
        this.otdXmfyEditable=true
      }else if(row.stage=='stage3' && this.user.posts.some(item=>item.postCode=='GSPG1-N(530)')){
        row.hasAuth=true
        this.onenRgcbEditable=true
        this.onenXmfyEditable=true
      }else if(this.user.posts.some(item=>item.postCode=='GSPGDSF(530)')){
        row.hasAuth=true
        this.sqXmfyEditable=true
        this.otdXmfyEditable=true
        this.onenXmfyEditable=true
        this.csXmfyEditable=true
      }else if(this.user.posts.some(item=>item.postCode=='GSPGDL(530)')){
        row.hasAuth=true
        this.sqXmfyEditable=true
        this.otdXmfyEditable=true
        this.onenXmfyEditable=true
        this.csXmfyEditable=true
      }
    }
}
```

the method analysisAuth(row) will change the data property sqXmfyEditable as true, then the add button will be editable.
But button is disable.

I searched, and asked our frontend engineer, he told me he haven't found the errors.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: I figured it out, it needs me add slot-scope="scope" to the <template slot="header">